# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I've started a rails project using `rails new` with `--webpack=react`.

I generated a new controller updated my PostgreSQL password in the database.yml.

Up to this point, everything works fine. At this point all I'm trying to do is get react to render the default hello_react.jsx file that was generated as an example by rails.

When I put `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>` in my view and run the server I get the following error:

> Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index Showing
> G:/../../../myGroceryList/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #1
> raised:
>
> Webpacker can't find hello_react.js in
> G:/../../../myGroceryList/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
>
> You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your
> environment unless you are using the webpack -w or the
> webpack-dev-server. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates. You
> have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file. Your webpack
> configuration is not creating a manifest. Your manifest contains: { }

I have pushed the [project up to GitHub.](https://github.com/Jonny-B/groceryList) Any thought on what is going wrong and how to fix this error?

RESOLVED: Resolution in comments

Comment: Here is a your project with small changes here I am using sqlite3 db and I am using ruby 2.5.1 and I did standard commands like: bundle install
and if everything pass okay you should see the page you wish, no problem: Then just use `rails s` Here is project:https://github.com/nezirz/groceryList [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwNls.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwNls.png) Also check the if you have any other errors in console if sites does not shows.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and see if it works.

Comment: Ok. So I've pulled your project down and updated to ruby 2.5.1. I'm having issues getting sqlite3 installed and compiled so I switch back to pg. Still seeing the error. So, at this point the only difference is the db which would be a strange reason to see this error. I'm trying again to get sqlite3 installed so we will see if I can eliminate that.

Comment: ok, because in my case I didnt need to use pg db, it was easier to use sqlite3 just to test this case,  what is the error about sqlite3?

Comment: I got sqlite3 working and I'm still getting that original webpack error. Further. I've set all this up on a different computer than when I first ran into the issue. At this point there should be no differences in what we are running. I'm very confused.

Comment: did you run yarn install? did you installed webpack?

Comment: can you try some other tutorial then? https://cognitiveclass.ai/blog/react-on-rails-tutorial-integrating-react-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: hehe I am supposing that you are missing some basic steps but from your error I cant see what.

Comment: RESOLUTION: As best I can tell this error fires when your public/packs folder is missing the Manifest file or is missing all together. What was happening in my case was Webpackers compilation step was silently failing and not creating the public/packs folder.

Comment: Reinstalling webpacker in the newly created rails project using `rake webpacker:install` fixed it for me.

Comment: Here is my solution for future Rails 6.1+ and Ruby 2.7.1+ users. For me it happened because my webpacker gem was set to 4.0 in the `Gemfile`. Once I raised it to 5.0 and ran `bundle update`, this error went away for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RESOLUTION: As best I can tell this error fires when your public/packs folder is missing the Manifest file or is missing all together. What was happening in my case was Webpackers compilation step was silently failing and not creating the public/packs folder. I checked in a fix to the webpacker gem for this. You can see that fix and conversation [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1730).

if this is the root cause then you can fix with either of these depending on how you prefer to install node packages
`yarn install`
or
`npm install`

Comment: Here is my solution for future Rails 6.1+ and Ruby 2.7.1+ users. For me it happened because my webpacker gem was set to 4.0 in the `Gemfile`. Once I raised it to 5.0 and ran `bundle update`, this error went away for me. I am guessing it was silently failing on my app and not creating the folders because I had the wrong version number specified.

Comment: as of the next version of Webpacker, I am pleased to report that the contributions made on this SO answer has helped improve the error message itself! https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/3232

Comment: Awesome. I glad this all made a contribution.

Comment: I was having this issue in my Rails test environment after a webpack upgrade -- it was because I needed to prefix my webpack compile command with `NODE_ENV=test`

Answer (score 11):

[Jonny B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254473/jonny-b),

I encountered the same issue. I was able to determine that I needed to add '.jsx' to my `webpacker.yml`.

```yaml
   extensions:
     - .js
+    - .jsx
     - .sass
     - .scss
     - .css
```

I also found that `webpacker:compile` was not being run on page refresh or when files were changed. I needed to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` (or `bundle exec rake webpacker:compile`) manually after each change to be able to reload and see the changes.

I am running the application via Apache+Mod_Passenger rather than using `rails s` (I have too many apps in development at the same time to keep starting and stopping a server on the command line). It seems like this doesn't work well with Webpacker's compile-on-demand functionality. Starting a server with `rails s` will allow me to hit the app on `localhost:3000`, but the react app doesn't render correctly. *After* hitting the page via the Puma server on 3000, I can now see the compiled assets working in my Apache/Passenger instance. So, the on-demand compiling seems to only work properly when running in a server started on the command line (`rails s`) ...which doesn't render correctly. :-/

The other option (better than running 2 servers) is to compile on the command line using `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` or `bundle exec rake webpacker:compile` whenever you make a change. Still a PITA, but at least it works ...for now. If I find a better solution, I'll update the answer.

### UPDATE

After a *lot* of playing around, installing different version of NodeJS, Ruby, rbenv, nvm, etc., I was able to determine that the `NODE_ENV` wasn't being set for the Apache/Passenger environment. Using Rbenv, I was able to add an `.rbenv-vars` file in my app root containing:

```
NODE_ENV=development
RACK_ENV=development
RAILS_ENV=development
```

Now, Webpacker (and NodeJS) see that I am running in development rather than production, and the compile-on-demand is working.

Comment: Adding .jsx to webpacker.yml solved this problem for me.