# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError with a vanilla Rails 6 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

Software versions on a macOS 10.14.6 and 10.15:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.0
$ node -v
v6.14.4
```

## Setup

```
$ rails new testshop3
$ cd testshop3
$ rails g scaffold Product name price:integer
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails s
```

This seems to be a very simple and straight forward setup but when I open `http://localhost:3000/products` I get the error message "Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Products#index".

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639256/webpackermanifestmissingentryerror)

Comment: Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for the problem. But unfortunately I changed too many things at the same time so I have a hard time to pin down what the exact solution is. Here's what I did:

- upgrade brew
- uninstall and install RVM
- install ruby 2.6.3
- install rails 6.0.0
- install nodejs 10.16.3 (after checking https://nodejs.org for the LTS)

After that it worked. Maybe the last step would have fixed the problem in the first place but I have no way of checking that.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a nearly identical problem with node v11.5.0. My first idea was to run either of these:

```
>bundle exec rake assets:precompile
>rails assets:precompile
```

Both commands fail using yarn v1.10.1, because the yarn CLI can't find a "webpack" command.